# Multiple response variables for bam function in mgcv R-Package?

Tags: r, mgcv

I am wondering if it is possible to have multiple response variables as input in the bam function (mgcv R-Package)? For example:

mdl <- bam(A1 + A2 + A3 ~ C + s(P, by=C) + s(P, N, by = C, bs = "fs", k = 10), data = DATA)

where A1-A3 are response variables, C is a 3-level factor, P is x-domain (range 0-100), N is a random factor (70-levels).

I have been playing around and there is an effect on the results, however, I am unsure how the smooths are being used aka summed and then applied or smoothed and then summed. My question stems from using a SLDA to identify which response variables are important to a classification model and then use these response variables to identify "where" there are differences between fitted class models.

Like I said there has been an effect, but I would like to better understand how multiple response variables affect the GAMM results.